# Power monitoring on a three phase system with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino

**Hello**

I am currently working on a project, where I want to measure the voltage and current in a 3-phase system with an Arduino Uno.

This is a small schoolproject and I've had the necessary course on AC-systems to know about safety around higher voltages. I've also have a little bit experience with microcontroller but I've never used ADC.

I have a problem when reading from the analog pins of the Arduino Uno. It seems like the analog pins are mixed which i believe is called ghosting. I've been searching the internet for some answers to this matter, but the proposed solutions didn't work for me. I tried to make a dummy measurement and also to make a small time delay between measurements but since it's about power monitoring timing is critical. I need at minimum 20 readings which needs to be done in 20ms

To test the code I used two function generators. Is this even possible or allowed? Is it best to have at minimum a resistance in between and maybe a capacitor to remove noise?

Is there something in the circuit when transforming the voltage/current to be between 0V-5V there can be done to prevent this ghosting-effect? 
I am using a voltagetransformer for the voltage and a Hall-effect sensor for the current. Both circuits need offset.

**This is the code that makes the measurements.**

```
void measure(char pin_volt, char pin_curr, int *volt_rms, int *curr_rms, float *theta){
  int i;
  long squared_v, squared_c, sum_squared_v = 0, sum_squared_c = 0, inst_v, inst_c, mean_squared_v, mean_squared_c;
  unsigned long time_v, time_c;
  for(i = 0; i < samples; i++){
    inst_v = analogRead(pin_volt) - volt_offset;
    if(inst_v > -volt_varying && inst_v <  volt_varying) {
      time_v = micros();
    }
    inst_c = analogRead(pin_curr) - curr_offset;
    if(inst_c >=  -curr_varying && inst_c <=  curr_varying) {
      time_c = micros();
    }
    squared_v = inst_v * inst_v;
    squared_c = inst_c * inst_c;
    sum_squared_v += squared_v;
    sum_squared_c += squared_c;
    delayMicroseconds(80);
  }
  mean_squared_v = sum_squared_v / samples;
  mean_squared_c = sum_squared_c / samples;
  *volt_rms = sqrt(mean_squared_v);
  *curr_rms = sqrt(mean_squared_c);
  *theta = calculate_phase_difference(time_v,time_c); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a capacitor can lower the problem.
Try to do the following:

No current or tension on the circuit, so the arduino should measure 0 values.

Run a sketch that reads values and prints max and min values to serial monitor; you will see that values will not be zero as expected, those are interferences.
Try and find a capacitor that can lower those values but don't exagerate.